# Mysql retrieve results of update query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am developing high load web-application and trying to reduce the quantity of sql queries. Quite often I need to update one row and get the results. I think it would be nice to have possibility to run query and at the same time receive the values of updated fields without making 2 calls of mysql server. For example, I execute the following query:

`update table set val=val+1 where id=1;`

and function returns:

`array("val"=>10)`

Sure, I understand, that I can write my own function, which first makes update, than select and returns the result. But the problem is that in such case mysql server will have to seek data, update during first query, than comes the second query, which again requires to seek data and return it. And I am thinking about the way, where mysql seeks data, updates and returns updated data.

Comment: From MySQL doc: `Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Btw, that would be a transaction - not a function